# Is it legal to terminate employee after them not signing an optional contract?

Tags: germany, workplace

I asked [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/127086/company-forcing-employee-to-take-courses-outside-working-hours-what-to-do) a few days ago at Workplace.SE community.

The contract stated what I mentioned in the linked question, plus that in twenty years his salary would be around 50-something thousand Euros.

Since the document was *optional* to sign and required Jim to take online courses outside working hours and pay for them himself, (also having a low salary raise) he decided not to sign it.

A few days after this event, the company notified Jim that he's being terminated, with the reason given that *he wasn't planning to stay with the company long-term(20 years)*.

Can a company give this reason to fire an employee after they decide not to sign an optional contract? Is it legal in Germany?

Comment: It would be legal in the U.S., I don't have a way to determine what is allowed in Germany. The precise nature of his employment agreement would also matter (was there a written contract, is he in a union, what is the nature of the job, etc.).

Comment: The practice of the company feels highly dubious and is likely to be frowned upon in a German labor court. However, that depends a lot on what the actual employment contract says and what the employee willingly agreed to. Without the details of this contract,  it's hard to comment

Comment: Doesn't sound very optional.